# Cassandra immediate consistency with RF=2 and CL=1

Tags: cassandra, lucene

I have a setup with RF=2 and all my read/writes are done with CL=1. There are few places where i open a session, write an entry, backend processin and read again. This mostly works but sometimes the read returns Nil. We are suspecting that the read's from the co-ordinator node goes to a node that is different from where the Write was done. My understanding is that a co-ordinator node sends the read request to both replica nodes and return the results correctly.

We are not worried about the updates to a row as most of the time we need immediate consistency only for newly created row's. We really don't need Quoram and the RF=2 is mostly for HA to tolerate the loss of one node. Any pointers on how to acheive immediate consistency with RF=2 and CL=1 is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You pretty much can’t have immediate consistency with CL=1 in a multinode cluster.

Answer (score 1):

have a RF=3 with QUORUM would give you immediate consistency with ability to have single node loss. Anything less then that and its impossible to guarantee it as there will always be windows where one node sees mutation before other.

```
R + W > N  to have a consistent read/write.
R (number of nodes needed for read) + W (number of nodes needed for write) > N (number of nodes with data, RF)
```

with CL 1 on reads/writes and RF=2 you have 1+1 which is not > 2. You can use ALL, TWO or QUORUM on either read or write and you would get your consistency (only because rf=2 for TWO and QUORUM) but then any node failure will bring down abilities to do either reads or writes.

Comment: Thanks Chris for the response. We are mostly likely go and use Rf=3 and Quoram. I wanted to see if anyone has experience is using read_repair_chance=1. With this I can write with CL=1 but reads will be equivalent to CL=ALL and still tolerate one node failure as per  https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.1/cassandra/operations/opsRepairNodesReadRepair.html

Comment: You will be able to handle node failures but it wont make the queries consistent. A CL.ONE query with read repair = 1.0 will still return inconsistent data, but if there are inconsistencies they will asynchronously fixed _after_ your query has returned to you. This is different than blocking read repairs you get at higher consistency levels.